# Sweetalert2 email validation not working

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am trying to use Sweetalert2 to validate inputs but I can't get it to work.  The below code opens the pop-up then correctly identifies incorrect email addresses but the second swal doesn't appear if a correct one is entered, nothing happens.

```
(async function getEmail() {
  const {value: email} = await swal({
      title: 'Input email address',
      input: 'email',
      inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your email address'
  })

  if (email) {
      swal('Entered email: ' + email)
  }
])()
```

On further investigation I have found that if I remove the if argument, a pop up appears saying 'Entered email: undefined' so the actual email address isn't being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `const {value: email} = await` with `const email = await` at which point it started to work